# PHP/AJAX Error from DevDemon Campaigns When Posting to Facebook

Tags: ajax, php-errors, devdemon-campaigns

I'm getting the following error when I try to post to one of my Facebook pages from Campaigns:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: services/service.isgd.php
>
> Line Number: 53
>
> {"success":true,"errorMsg":"","errors":> [{"box_id":2,"campaign_order":1,"error":"shortenUrl(): "},> {"box_id":2,"campaign_order":1,"error":"shortenUrl(): "}],"campaignId":""}

Does anyone know of a way to resolve this? I am running EE 2.11.2, and Campaigns 2.2.0

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Facebook API changes. The patch supplied by Vector Media for this is as follows

system/expressionengine/third_party/campaigns/services/service.facebook.php, line 90. Replace:

```
$html .= '<a href="'.$res->link.'" target="_blank">View Profile</a>';
```

With this:

```
$html .= '<a href="'.@$res->link.'" target="_blank">View Profile</a>';
```

And system/expressionengine/third_party/campaigns/views/status/facebook.php, lines 19 and 20. Replace:

```
        <strong>From Account: </strong> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?=$fbData->from->id?>" target="_blank"><?=$fbData->from->name?></a><br>
        <strong>Link: </strong> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?=$fbData->id?>" target="_blank">https://www.facebook.com/<?=$fbData->id?></a><br>
```

With this:

```
        <strong>From Account: </strong> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?=@$fbData->from->id?>" target="_blank"><?=@$fbData->from->name?></a><br>
        <strong>Link: </strong> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?=@$fbData->id?>" target="_blank">https://www.facebook.com/<?=@$fbData->id?></a><br>
```